# Are there advantages to using a Vector to implement a stack versus just using an array?

Tags: java, vector, stack

Is there any advantage of using vector in java to implement a stack compared to using just an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key difference between Arrays and Vectors in Java is that Vectors are dynamically-allocated. They aren't declared to contain a type of variable; instead, each Vector contains a dynamic list of references to other objects.
The big advantage of using Vectors is that the size of the vector can change as needed. Vectors handle these changes through the "capacity" and "capacityIncrement" fields. 
Because Vectors are dynamically-allocated, they offer a relatively memory-efficient way of handling lists whose size could change drastically.
So for stack vectors are preferable.
I hope this helps.